# /wp-admin/ works but website doesn't load

Tags: wp-admin

I was doing some small code changes on the theme, just changed HTML in one of the templates, and my website stopped working. I'm getting "This page isn’t working" HTTP ERROR 500 but only when I visit the website, wp admin works without problems.

Here is what I tried so far, but nothing worked:
1. Disable all plugins
2. Turn on WP_DEBUG and WP_DEBUG_LOG from wp-config.php - I'm not getting any error
3. Increase the memory limit to512M

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Perhaps rename the template you were changing so that it won't be used?

Comment: I also tried to deactivate the theme I was changing and to activate one of Twenty theme. It didn't help.

Comment: Have you looked at the error.log file? In the folder of your site, and/or the wp-admin folder? And the access logs of your server (separate from the error.log file).

Comment: I have only FTP login so I can't check server logs. I don't have any logs in WP folders. WP_DEBUG_LOG creates log file in wp-content if there are any errors, as far as I know, but I have no error files.

Comment: If you rename the active theme folder to something else, that will deactivate it, and use one of the Twenty themes. That might get you access. Assuming you have WP 5.2? That should help you recover from white screen errors. You'll need hosting 'cpanel' access to look at server logs. You could also try reinstalling your theme files from a backup copy. Or maybe even a manual update/reinstall of WP (not a fresh install, since you don't want to overwrite config files. Codex has instructions on manual updates.

Comment: Since you have admin access, you could try deleting the theme, then reinstalling it. It's possible the theme doesn't delete it's options/settings on an uninstall/reinstall. Database backup first. But I'd try the theme folder rename first, and also a WP reinstall via the Updates page.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to update WordPress to the latest version.

I tried deleting the theme and to run the website, it didn't work. It's very awkward how the website crashed down and I was surprised that updating WordPress actually solved the problem.

Thanks, to everyone who tried to help!